# Click to dial in MS dynamics 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

In MS dynamics there is support click to dial support for Lync and Skype.

Where you click on phone number call dial through skype or lync.

I want to achieve same, but I want to route call from my telephony application using JAVA script.

Is there onclick event for phone attribute, where I can handle that event and call my script function.

Currently I could see only change event.

Or is there any other way to achieve same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there isn't a supported way to tie into the click event of a text field. You could expose a "Call" button in a web resource (iFrame) on the page or by doing unsupported changes to the HTML on the page.

I hope this helps.